# Porting ShaderToy to Pixi.js

Tags: javascript, glsl, webgl, pixi.js, shadertoy

Im trying to port this shadertoy [shadertoy](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/lsBfDz) to pixi.js.

Here is my shader:

```c
uniform vec3 iResolution;
uniform float iTime;
uniform float iTimeDelta;
uniform float iFrameRate;
uniform int iFrame;
uniform float iChannelTime[4];
uniform vec3 iChannelResolution[4];
uniform vec4 iMouse;
uniform vec4 iDate;

varying vec2 vTextureCoord;
uniform sampler2D uSampler;
uniform sampler2D noise;

#define T texture2D(noise,(s*p.zw+ceil(s*p.x))/2e2).y/(s+=s)*4.

void main(){

    vec4 O;
    vec2 x;

    vec4 p,d=vec4(.8,0,x/iResolution.y-.8),c=vec4(.6,.7,d);
    O=c-d.w;

    for(float f,s,t=2e2+sin(dot(x,x));--t>0.;p=.05*t*d)
        p.xz+=iTime,
        s=2.,
        f=p.w+1.-T-T-T-T,
        f<0.?O+=(O-1.-f*c.zyxw)*f*.4:O;
}
```

and this is my javascript:

```js
const GLOBAL_WIDTH = window.innerWidth;
const GLOBAL_HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;

var app = new PIXI.Application({ width: GLOBAL_WIDTH, height: GLOBAL_HEIGHT, resolution: 1, backgroundAlpha: 1, antialias: true });

document.body.appendChild(app.view);

PIXI.Assets.load('perlin.jpg').then(onAssetsLoaded);

var filter = null;

var totalTime = 0;

var fragShader = document.getElementById('fragShader').innerHTML;

function onAssetsLoaded(perlin) {

    perlin.baseTexture.wrapMode = PIXI.WRAP_MODES.REPEAT;
    perlin.baseTexture.mipmap = false;
    perlin.width = perlin.height = 200;

    filter = new PIXI.Filter(null, fragShader, {
        iResolution: [GLOBAL_WIDTH, GLOBAL_HEIGHT, 1.0],
        iTime: 0.0,
        noise: perlin
    });

    app.stage.filterArea = app.renderer.screen;
    app.stage.filters = [filter];

    app.ticker.add((delta) => {
        filter.uniforms.iTime = totalTime;
        totalTime += delta / 60;
    });
}
```

Im getting this error:

> ```
> ERROR: 0:27: 'for' : Invalid init declaration
> ```

Comment: I have zero knowledge of GLSL. Do you mean the brackets of the for loop? Or do you suggest putting brackets on all the code? I just put brackets on the for loop and still the same error

Comment: So you are wrong here. Please read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users).

Answer (score 0):

See [The OpenGL® Shading Language, Version 4.60.7](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.60.html)

> ERROR: 0:27: 'for' : Invalid init declaration

This means that you cannot do initializations of multiple variables in the init statement of the `for` loop

<s>`for(float f,s,t=`</s>

The curly braces are missing and statements must be terminated with a semicolon. In GLSL code, code blocks must be between `{` and `}` and there must be a `;` at the end of each statement. e.g:

```c
float f, s;
for(float t = 2e2+sin(dot(x,x)); --t>0.; p=.05*t*d) {
    p.xz += iTime;
    s = 2.;

    // [...]
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Now the error is: ERROR: 0:32: 'assign' : cannot convert from 'mediump 4-component vector of float' to 'mediump float'.

Comment: I think the error is in the last line of the for loop

Comment: There ate many mor errors in your code.  I'll not debug your code.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your time, and sorry for my english, i'm going to keep googling